# scrolling to elements on mobile or tablet is making it scroll too much

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a project for school and the scrolling plugin I used is working great for my screen size but it is scrolling below the title names on tablet or mobile screen sizes. I'm unsure why this is happening, anyone have any ideas?  http://www.sleeksurvey.com

Comment: Have you tried to animate your navigation bar sooner? It looks like the animation does not start until you get to About Us. This would give you more room to adjust the scrollTop of the window probably by adding a higher number then by just using the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /resources/css/queries.css, your CSS for smaller screens sets the section padding smaller, for example, line 49:

```
section { padding: 30px 0; }
```

If you change that (and there's something similar on line 117) to:

```
section { padding: 60px 0; }
```

that should solve your scrolling problem. It may introduce other issues, but it's a good start.